# How do I turn my Google Maps into just an image? And not movable using the mouse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

My javascript code is this:

```
var myOptions = {
            scrollwheel:false,
            zoom: 15,
            center: the_lat_long,
            mapTypeControl:false,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are just wanting to render a static image, I would just use the [Google Maps Static API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/).  This would just result in a regular `<img>` tag with a api called url as the `src=`.  I would prefer this option because there is no reason to use the overhead of the javascript api if a simple `<img>` tag does the job for you.

Comment: Have you got any recommendations on how to use this with a list of json styles? My JS file has the map options also. To put this into a url is very taxing..

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the [draggable](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MapOptions) option:

```
var myOptions = {
    ...,
    draggable: false
}
```

By default dragging is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Goggle maps api's](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html)   [**disableDragging()**](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GMap2.disableDragging)

Or use the [Static map api](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/)