# convert Google JavaScript map with overlays to single image

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I've created a Google map with circle overlays, much like [this one](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/circle-simple). I want to include this map in a PDF (along with some other graphics) that will be created on the server side. It seems the easiest way to do this would be to convert the map to a single image and upload it to the server. Is it possible to do this with JavaScript?

Alternatively, I could try to convert it to an image and create the PDF on the client-side, but it seems this would be a lot more difficult.

Anyhow, the first step is converting the map to an image. I've considered using the static maps API to generate the image, but it seems this API does not support the circle overlays.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I turn my Google Maps into just an image? And not movable using the mouse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776417/how-do-i-turn-my-google-maps-into-just-an-image-and-not-movable-using-the-mouse)

Comment: @Dancrumb I don't think I can use the static maps API (as proposed in the linked question) because it doesn't support the circle overlays

Comment: good point. Also... big fan of your avatar :)

Comment: @Dancrumb thanks, remarkably, there are actually some BBC programming questions on this site, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16334274